# How to increase timeout for retrofit requests in robospice android?

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I have implemented robospice in my project and using retrofit for all api calls. For some of requests, I need to increase timeout, please let me know how can I do that?

Actually I am using service that extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService.
The code of my service class is below:

```
public class MyService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        addRetrofitInterface(MyInterface.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        ObjectPersisterFactory persistFactory = new RetrofitObjectPersisterFactory(application,
                getConverter(), getCacheFolder());

        persistFactory.setAsyncSaveEnabled(true);
        cacheManager.addPersister(persistFactory);

        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServerUrl() {
        return Utils.getBaseUrl();
    }

    @Override
    protected RestAdapter.Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setRequestInterceptor(
                new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addHeader(Const.HEADER_DEVICE_TYPE_KEY,
                                Const.HEADER_DEVICE_TYPE_VALUE);
                    }
                }
        );
        builder.setEndpoint(getServerUrl()).setConverter(getConverter());
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I stumbled in here with a similar question and eventually found the answer elsewhere. Had there been a more complete example here, I would have saved some time so I circled back to post what worked for me just in case it helps others:

### Adapter with increased read timeout

```
    // create client
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // create rest adapter using the client above
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getBaseApiUrl())
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            // this gson converter below is optional. We use it for parsing dates and enums
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(createApiGson()))
            .setLogLevel(getRetrofitLogLevel())
            .build();
```

**NOTE:** for us, `getBaseApiUrl()` returns something like: `https://some.company.com/api/`
and `getRetrofitLogLevel()` returns either `RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL` or `RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE` depending on which flavor of the app is built.

Lastly, these are the main dependencies that make everything work:

### Key dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.5.0"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.4"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `RetrofitSpiceService` extending service, you'll need to override `createRestAdapterBuilder()`.

```
 @Override
 protected Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
    Builder builder = super.createRestAdapterBuilder();
    builder.setClient(new CustomClient());
    return builder;
  }
```

`CustomClient` is the class that you need to write yourself to supply your own timeouts. If you're using OkHttp, take a look at the default `OkClient` for reference: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/43b7ea14e5aca1d710deccb95b79484b03e99bb9/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/OkClient.java

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about robospice but with retrofit 2+ and okhttp3+ you should set a new client like this.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constantes.URL_DOMAIN)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Constantes.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(Constantes.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(Constantes.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
            .build();
```

import this in your module build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
```