# Change ConnectionTimeout of Retrofit OkHttpClient at runtime

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger, robospice

I am using Dagger to inject RestAdapter.Builder and I am making an OkHttpClient inside that function. The function is as follows:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("JSON")
public RestAdapter.Builder provideJsonRestAdapterBuilder(final ChangeableEndpoint changeableEndpoint,
                                                         final Set<RequestInterceptor> requestInterceptors) {
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(Constants.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setWriteTimeout(Constants.WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(Constants.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(mApplication.getCacheDir(), Constants.CACHE_SIZE));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOG.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(AbstractAction.class, new AbstractActionDeserializer())
        .create();

    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .setEndpoint(changeableEndpoint)
        .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
        .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public void intercept(final RequestFacade request) {
                for (final RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor : requestInterceptors) {
                    requestInterceptor.intercept(request);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

If you see I am currently providing a constant when setting setConnectTimeout. But this value will now be coming from server so I need to set it again. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: This Question has already been answered:

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669309/how-to-increase-timeout-for-retrofit-requests-in-robospice-android